# Setting LAS Class Codes in ArcGIS Pro too slow

Tags: arcgis-pro, classification, extract, las, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have seen similar questions, but they don't quite relate to my particular issue.

I classified habitat in a high-resolution drone orthomosaic image of a 300-m long stretch of beach, then used **Raster to Polygon** to convert the classified raster to vector format.  I only have a few different classes: sand and several classes of seaweed.  However, because the seaweed is scattered across the beach in many different shapes and sizes, many many polygons were generated for each class from **Raster to Polygon** (I used this tool with and without checking the Multipart Feature option, both have the same result).  This has proven to be problematic for my next step: classifying the LAS point cloud.

I have an unclassified LAS point cloud generated from Drone Deploy that I now need to classify according to those habitat polygons.  The **Set LAS Class Codes Using Features** tool is just the tool I need and I know it works - I just classified my LAS point cloud using one large survey area polygon as the input 'Feature' to classify to and it processed in seconds.

However, this tool is not yet able to finish processing the LAS points using the habitat class polygons, as each class is comprised of many many multipart polygons. By struggling, I mean it has yet to process anything past 13%, even after an overnight run for over 9 hrs. I have tried this tool on ArcGIS Pro 2.5, 2.6, and Desktop, as well as the Extract LAS tool, all with the same result.  The original LAS point cloud was 15 million points, so I also just used the **Thin LAS** tool to limit the points to ~5 million.  This is currently running overnight on the habitat class with the smallest coverage, so stay tuned.

Is there any way around this problem in ArcGIS Pro?

This is time-sensitive and I have multiple habitat classes to reclassify. Again, this works great one one simple polygon, but not in my case where each class is comprised of thousands of different shaped polygons.  At this rate it will take days to classify the LAS point cloud for one image, time I don't really have.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please include links to the similar questions that you say you've seen before.  That way any potential answerers will be able to save their volunteered time looking for them before deciding whether to try and answer your question.

Comment: It is unwise to use multi-part polygons to attribute a very large point sample, since the larger envelope makes the spatial index less effective.  Use MultipartToSinglepart on the polygons first. Please do not make statements of urgency in your posts -- The most likely result is that it will slow response time and accumulate downvotes.

Comment: Thank you Vince!  Not using multipart features was my initial thought as well, so in another test, I left this parameter unchecked when converting the raster to polygons.  This resulted in 479,500 polygons, however.  The processing did not immediately seem enhanced.

That said, thinning the LAS point cloud seems to have helped with processing speed thus far, but processing is not yet complete.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: The problem may be the number and complexity of the polygons, is it possible to set all LAS to a default class (las2las -set_class) and then run your tool on only the polygons where the class is different to the default? There is also an Esri tool https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/set-las-class-codes-using-features.htm if you have 3d analyst but no guarantee that that is any better than what you already have.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  In fact, Set LAS Class Codes Using Features in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 is the tool that I am running that I mentioned previously (now going on 30 hrs, but still progressing).  There may not be any way around this, unless I seriously simplify my polygons.  'Simplify Polygons' is actually an optional parameter in the previous Raster to Polygon step, and I did choose to simplify.

Comment: Update:  The tool eventually ran successfully after 30 hours.